# Are LogCat calls computationally expensive in Android?

Tags: android, logcat

I want to do some performance benchmarking of some blocks of code in my Android app. My plan is to measure `System.nanoTime()` at various points and then spit out the difference to the Logcat.

However, I was wondering if calls to `Log.i()` itself were actually computationally expensive and therefore might skew the results?

Internally I do not know what `Log.i(...)` is actually doing - is it writing direct to some output stream on the USB or is it just placing the log message onto a queue to be picked up by some asynchronous thread which does the real work?

Answer (score 4):

it could give you an idea of what it is going on, but it will be never be really precise. You should use one of the profile tool of android (you can find it [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html)). The Log.* is completely asynchronous, but I do not know the implementation details

Answer (score 1):

Firstly thanks to @Blackbelt for your answer, you are correct to a certain extent but I wanted to add more detail and objective measurements.

I did some benchmarking using both System.nanoTime() and [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) and the results were remarkably similar.

I did a series of tests executing very trivial one line statements in a tight for loop whilst measuring the time before and after the line. I then took an average of these:

```
Log.i("testLogcat", message); // mean execution time: 30465ns 

strings.add("test"); // mean execution time: 962ns 

Object x = new Object(); // mean execution time: 1185ns 

int x = 1+1; // mean execution time: 1053ns
```

As you can see the simple call to `Log.i()` is in fact relatively heavyweight, it is around 30 times more expensive than adding a string to an array list for example.

So there are 2 lessons here!

1. `Log.i()` is actually relatively slow and will effect execution time if you are working in the nanosecond range. It's ok to use it to spit out results AFTER using System.nanoTime() for measurements but not if the `Log.i()` calls are placed WITHIN the code being measured.
2. Ultimately the best tool for the job is [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html)

Comment: I actually posted a link to Traceview

Comment: Apologies, don't know how I got that, updated my answer

Comment: no worries. I am glad you found out what you were looking for.